# switch case statment with window location href as my case

Tags: jquery, switch-statement, window.location

I am looking to use a switch case statement for my different conditions in the location href. I am trying to avoid to keep writing if statements

```
if (/red/.test(self.location.href)){
   //do this red
 }

if (/blue/.test(self.location.href)){
   //do this blue
}

if (/yello/.test(self.location.href)){
  //do this yellow
}
```

Comment: depends on the rest of the URL, but you can do something like `var url = "http://yoursite.com/red"; var color = url.replace('http://yoursite.com/','');` then switch on color. the basic idea is to set a base url, then remove the base url from the current url

Comment: Can you explain your *exact* problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var _url = window.location.href;
swith(true){
    case /red/.test(_url):
    //do red
    break;
    case /blue/.test(_url):
    //do blue
    break;
    case /yellow/.test(_url):
      // do yellow
    break;
 }
```

Comment: I'd just go with an `if` block.

Comment: Thanks James. Do you think have 20 if conditonal statements is cleaner?

Comment: btw - if you accept my answer, please 'check it'!! lol.. trying to get up my rep :-) . In relation to your question, there have been a few jsperf tests and "if" statements seem to win out in terms of performance. For smaller groupings, I personally like the switch statment. But I think for something like 20, if/else if might give you a bigger bang for your buck if you expect high traffic.

Comment: There is a delay on me accepting I have to wait "2minutes" Thanks for the help

Comment: There is a typo here, it must be 'switch'.